# Can a non-resident tourist buy a gun for use back in his country?

Tags: air-travel, can

Can a non-resident tourist buy a gun for use in their countries? I need to buy one for use in Tanzania.

Comment: how would you go through the background check stuff?

Comment: Which country are you hoping to buy from? Regardless, surely it would be less work to buy within Tanzania than to do all the paperwork to legally transfer your new firearm from one country to another?

Comment: i want to buy it in the US

Comment: "Need" is a strong word. It is very near impossible in today's world that you both are able to travel intercontinentally and _need_ a firearm. Consider not owning one.

Comment: Is Guangzhou known for its gun markets?

Comment: i think so i have been in Guangzhou several times but i never tried once

Comment: do u think i can it in there and take it to Tanzania??

Comment: Why is this a duplicate? The other question is about a tourist carrying a gun while in the USA. This is a question about purchasing a gun for export. The question may well be closed on other grounds. But it isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

If you can **legally own** it in the origin country and the destination country, you might be able to arrange the import. It will require special handling if you bring it by air and lots of paperwork in advance.

- Hunters may be allowed to bring their own guns if they are allowed to hunt in the destination country. (That's not exactly your situation, right?)
- Sports shooters may be allowed to bring their guns to international competitions. That's quite routine in much of Europe, for example. (Again not quite your situation?)
- Importing a gun will be more complicated. *If you need to ask here, forget it.*